# Как сравнить две структуры

Tags: c++, c++11

Есть структура с несколькими полями

```
struct P {
  std::string name;
  int year;
  int month;
};
```

Как сравнить два таких объекта, так чтобы сначала они сравнивались по дате, а потом по имени?

Answer (score 28):

Для лексиграфического сравнения объектов по нескольким полям можно использовать функцию [`std::tie`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tie).

```
bool operator < (const P& a, const P& b) {
  return std::tie(a.year, a.month, a.name) < std::tie(b.year, b.month, b.name);
  // сначала сравнивается year, потом month, потом name.
}
```

`std::tie` возвращает временный объект - кортеж ссылок на поля `std::tuple<int&, int&, std::string&>`, у которого уже вызывается оператор "меньше".

Остальные операторы сравнения можно получить из оператора "меньше", написав их самому, либо при помощи [`std::rel_ops`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/rel_ops/operator_cmp) или [`Boost.Operators`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/master/libs/utility/operators.htm).

```
bool operator > (const P& a, const P& b) { return b < a; }
bool operator <= (const P& a, const P& b) { return !(b < a); }
bool operator >= (const P& a, const P& b) { return !(a < b); }
```

Чтобы избежать дублирования кода, можно написать вспомогательную функцию, которая будет превращать структуру в кортеж ссылок:

```
bool operator < (const P& a, const P& b) {
  auto tuple = [](const P& p) { return std::tie(p.year, p.month, p.name); };
  return tuple(a) < tuple(b);
}
```

Оператор сравнения можно также сделать членом самой структуры:

```
struct P {
  std::string name;
  int year;
  int month;

  bool operator < (const P& other) const {
    return std::tie(year, month, name) < std::tie(other.year, other.month, other.name);
  }
};
```

Так как сравнение не меняет саму структуру, то аргумент должен быть константной ссылкой, и сама функция должна быть константной.

В случае данной структуры, нет никакой разницы между свободной функцией и функцией-членом класса.
Однако если у структуры есть конструктор, позволяющий неявные преобразования типов, то надо использовать только свободную функцию:

```
struct Complex {
  Complex(int r = 0, int i = 0) : r(r), i(i) {}
  int r, i;
};
bool operator<(const Complex& a, const Complex& b);

int main() {
  Complex c(3, 4);
  c < 1; // свободная функция operator<(const Complex&, const Complex&),
         // один из аргументов - Complex, для второго аргумента делается
         // неявный вызов Complex(1), получается operator<(c, Complex(1))
  1 < c; // то же самое, получается operator<(Complex(1), c)
}
```

Если бы `operator<` был не свободной функцией, а функцией-членом `Complex`, то код `1 < c;` не скомпилировался бы т.к. у `1` (тип `int`) нет метода `<`.

Comment: Может быть, есть смысл добавить, куда и в каком виде лучше всего прописывать оператор сравнения? Это несамоочевидно, и часто делается неправильно (например, передача по значению и т. п.)

Comment: Для добавления операторов сравнения можно использовать `std::rel_ops`

Answer (score 2):

Следует перегрузить операторы сравнения (<, >, ==, !=, ...)

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky Поясняю, для собственных структур или классов не определены стандартные операции, такие как (+, -, /, *, >, <, ==, !=, &, ^ и т.д) И их следует реализовать самостоятельно.